# php functional-php library less_than function

Tags: php, functional-programming

I  saw in source code of [php-functional](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php/) library such function :

```
function less_than($b)
{
    return function ($a ) use ($b) {
        return $a < $b;
    };
}
```

I  can't get there `$a` comes from. How is this going to work?

We pass only `$b` to function less than and `$a` is undefined.

This is the link to source code [where I took it from.](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php/blob/master/src/Functional/LessThan.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of *functional programming* is that functions are first-class objects. So you can pass functions as parameters; and you can return functions.

So here you can construct a function:

```
$func_less = less_than(3);
```

So we basically construct a function like:

```
$func_less = function ($a) {
    return $a < 3;
};
```

and now `$func_less` is a function that takes a parameter `$a` and checks if that `$a` is less than three. For example:

```
php > $func_less_three = less_than(3);
php > var_dump($func_less_three(2));
bool(true)
php > var_dump($func_less_three(14));
bool(false)
```

So first we construct a function `$func_less_three`, then we call that function with two numbers `2` and `14`. Since `2` is less than `3`, it returns `bool(true)` on the first call, and since 14 is not less than 3, it return `bool(false)` on the second call.

In most functional programming languages like Haskell, all functions take exactly *one* parameter. So instead of adding two numbers together, one first constructs a function that adds a (in that function) constant value to a parameter.